# How could I boost my database loading time?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, database-migration

I'm working on a database migration on an windows application. It was previously an access database (file.accdb) and I am migrating it to a Sql Azure database. I've got an issue with the loading time when the application is started. The loading time has increased from ~5 seconds to more than 600 seconds.  I've located the issue and it's this method...

```
 private void LoadPSDTestPSDResult()
    {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM PSDTestPSDResultEuro";
        string sqlQuery2 = "SELECT * from PSDTestPSDResultEuroExtended WHERE SampleID = @sampleId AND PartAn = @partAn";

        using (DataTable results = LoadTable(sqlQuery))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
            {
                PSDTestPSDResultEuro newData = new PSDTestPSDResultEuro
                {
                    SampleID = (Int32)row["SampleID"]
                };

                if (row["PartAn"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.PartAn = (bool)row["PartAn"];
                if (row["0"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0 = (Double)row["0"];
                if (row["0,036"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_036 = (Double)row["0,036"];
                if (row["0,05"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_05 = (Double)row["0,05"];
                if (row["0,063"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_063 = (Double)row["0,063"];
                if (row["0,074"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_074 = (Double)row["0,074"];
                if (row["0,125"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_125 = (Double)row["0,125"];
                if (row["0,25"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_25 = (Double)row["0,25"];
                if (row["0,5"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_0_5 = (Double)row["0,5"];
                if (row["1"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_1 = (Double)row["1"];
                if (row["2"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_2 = (Double)row["2"];
                if (row["3,15"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_3_15 = (Double)row["3,15"];
                if (row["4"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_4 = (Double)row["4"];
                if (row["5"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_5 = (Double)row["5"];
                if (row["5,6"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_5_6 = (Double)row["5,6"];
                if (row["6,3"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_6_3 = (Double)row["6,3"];
                if (row["7,1"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_7_1 = (Double)row["7,1"];
                if (row["8"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_8 = (Double)row["8"];
                if (row["9"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_9 = (Double)row["9"];
                if (row["10"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_10 = (Double)row["10"];
                if (row["11,2"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_11_2 = (Double)row["11,2"];
                if (row["12,5"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_12_5 = (Double)row["12,5"];
                if (row["14"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_14 = (Double)row["14"];
                if (row["16"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_16 = (Double)row["16"];
                if (row["18"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_18 = (Double)row["18"];
                if (row["20"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_20 = (Double)row["20"];
                if (row["22,4"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_22_4 = (Double)row["22,4"];
                if (row["25"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_25 = (Double)row["25"];
                if (row["28"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_28 = (Double)row["28"];
                if (row["31,5"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_31_5 = (Double)row["31,5"];
                if (row["35,5"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_35_5 = (Double)row["35,5"];
                if (row["40"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_40 = (Double)row["40"];
                if (row["45"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_45 = (Double)row["45"];
                if (row["50"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_50 = (Double)row["50"];
                if (row["56"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_56 = (Double)row["56"];
                if (row["63"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_63 = (Double)row["63"];
                if (row["71"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_71 = (Double)row["71"];
                if (row["80"] != DBNull.Value)
                    newData.Sep_80 = (Double)row["80"];

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, conn, trans))
                {   
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sampleId", newData.SampleID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partAn", newData.PartAn);
                    using (DataTable extendedRow = new DataTable())
                    {
                        extendedRow.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                        if (extendedRow.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            DataRow row2 = extendedRow.Rows[0];
                            if (row2["90"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_90 = (Double)row2["90"];
                            if (row2["100"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_100 = (Double)row2["100"];
                            if (row2["112,5"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_112_5 = (Double)row2["112,5"];
                            if (row2["125"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_125 = (Double)row2["125"];
                            if (row2["150"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_150 = (Double)row2["150"];
                            if (row2["200"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_200 = (Double)row2["200"];
                            if (row2["250"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_250 = (Double)row2["250"];
                            if (row2["300"] != DBNull.Value)
                                newData.Sep_Over250 = (double)row2["300"];
                        }
                    }

                }
                m_Database.PSDTestPSDResultEuro.Add(newData);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried some different solutions, making the LoadPSDTestPSDResult parallel & async-await. This did not fix the issue. It wouldn't even start the program as "execution timed out", due to memory?

I was told that I could try and set indexes to see that there is not an incorrect loop going on?

I could also ask the query through the database instead of in the logic (code)? 
Is there any tips for "boosting" the loading time that I can read up on, or how would I best approach this issue?

*I will gladly edit the question to make it easier understandable*

This is the first migration I'm doing. I'm fresh out of school and this is my first job!

Comment: How many rows in this table `PSDTestPSDResultEuro` ?

Comment: `PSDTestPSDResultEuro`contains 5978 rows
`PSDTestPSDResultEuroExtended`contains 1203 rows

Comment: Here it your problem, your first query returns about mb (not a lot) however, you are requiring the database 6000 times,  If you need all that data at once, why dont use just write a join query.

Comment: If each sub query took 100ms, there is 10 minutes in (and of) itself

Comment: You are right. Is there any specific link or forum where I could get to know "join query" better, and how to use it?

Comment: Just look up join query, or ask new specific question how to join these 2 tables. However best to do some research first and at least have a try

Comment: I will look it up. If I can not find a solution I might ask another question. Although I will try first.

Comment: @TheGeneral, you should post your comment as the answer and FilipE92 should mark it as the answer. It'll help folks with similar issues searching.